# Why screen freezes every time I launch IE developer tool on IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, ie-developer-tools

I am using IE 11 as my company does not allow any other browser to be installed. Every time I launch IE developer tool on IE 11 the screen freezes. Is there any lighter version of IE developer tool or if there is any provision to disable some of the features of IE developer tool which will enable faster loading of the developer tool? Do we have any alternative to IE developer tool on IE 11?

Comment: I assume you mean the [IE developer tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg182326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), as the [IE developer toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359) doesn't work with IE 8+, right?

Comment: @SebastianZartner: Yes, I mean IE developer tool.

Comment: What do you mean by "the screen freezes"? Does it take long until they open or does the browser completely hang and you have to restart it?

Comment: You probably have to update IE. Here's news to that issue on Microsoft - seems to be fixed by now: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/801628/ie11-developer-tools-network-tab-causes-freeze

Answer (score 0):

The first start of the developer tools may take a bit longer as it is initializing its UI. Also switching to a different panel for the first time takes a moment as it is obviously loading it's panels at the time when you switch to them.

The subsequent opening of the developer tools and switching to other panels should work much faster.

Also because of that asynchronous loading it probably wouldn't make any difference to allow disabling certain features.

*Please note that this answer is just based on observance. I don't actually know whether there's a way to turn some of their features off, but I assume there's no way to do so.*